# Perturbation problem using Runge-Kutta 4

Tags: ode, numerics, c++, runge-kutta, error-estimation

I'm trying to evaluate the perturbations magnitude between 2 body orbiting a central one in three dimensions. In order to do this I need to have an estimate of the error, which I did using Richardson extrapolation as described [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/comparing-numerical-solutions-with-very-different-time-grids). I'm using Runge-Kutta 4 and also velocity Verlet. Things seems good in the unperturbed problem, which means I obtain an error $O(10^{-7})$ and $O(10^{-12})$ for Verlet and Runge-Kutta respectively by using a time step of $0.001$. When I consider the perturbations, only velocity Verlet still give me the expected error, while Runge-Kutta give me an error of the same order of Verlet, using the same previous time step. The same happens even if I reduce or increase the time step. Actually for the perturbed problem I already expected something bad related to the error, since that's what I obtained for the Richardson's fraction for Runge-Kutta

[image]

As it can be seen, the level of the figure should be about $2^p = 16$, but it's $2$ actually. That sort of spikes are present also in the same plot for velocity Verlet, but for the latter their magnitudes are much less than that in the plot above and the $F_h$ values are about $4$ anyway, as expected for Verlet. I checked all the Runge-Kutta code and the ode system code but I didn't find any error. Moreover I tested both methods with a simpler function obtaining correct results, so I can't understand the reason for such wrong error estimates for Runge-Kutta.

**Edit 1**

The function code is the following

```
vector<double> F(double t, vector<double> x, vector<CB> objs, vector<double> s) {
    //objs store the masses of the objects
    //s store the positions of the objects in the order [x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,...];
    //x store the positions and velocity of the target (perturbed) object in the order [x,Vx,y,Vy,z,Vz]
    vector<double> p(x.size(),0);
    double m, d;
    vector<double> y(x.size()/2,0); 

    for (int i = 0; i < objs.size(); i++) {
        //temporary store the mass of the i-th object
        m = objs[i].CB::getmass(); 
        //temporary store the position of the i-th object from the s vector
        y = {s[i*x.size()/2], s[i*x.size()/2 + 1], s[i*x.size()/2 + 2]}; 

        d = sqrt(pow((x[0] - y[0]),2) + pow((x[2] - y[1]),2) + pow((x[4] - y[2]),2));

        //x system
        p[0] = x[1];
        p[1] += -G*m*(x[0] - y[0])/pow(d,3); 
        //y system                           
        p[2] = x[3];
        p[3] += -G*m*(x[2] - y[1])/pow(d,3);
        //z system
        p[4] = x[5];
        p[5] += -G*m*(x[4] - y[2])/pow(d,3);
    }

    return p;
}
```

Comment: What is your setup approximately? A starting configuration using real planetary data, or some artificial initial condition like one planet on a circular orbit of radius 1 and period 1, the other at radius 5, with a fixed proportion of masses, so that setting the mass factor turns the interaction on or off?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I use real planetary data taken from JPL Horizon system, cause I need to analyze different planetary configurations, of which the simpler one involve Sun, Jupiter and Saturn, with Jupiter perturbed by Saturn, which corrispondes to the perturbed case of my question. The motion of every planet involved in the simulation start from perihelion. The refernce frame is centered on the Sun.

Comment: The errors oscillate like the periodic orbits, close to the zero-crossings you get the spikes. This can be prevented by taking the norm over all coordinate differences of the body. There must be something wrong with the method step that reduces the order to 1. How did you implement the perturbation? In the acceleration computation, or as something extra that is added to the method step?

Comment: @LutzLehmann The perturbations are implemented in the acceleration computation. They're "turned on" if more than one object is considered in the computations.

Comment: Some hour ago I also compared my results to the one obtained using another Runge-Kutta 4 implementaion I found, but I got the same results for $F_h$.

Comment: I used the simplified model with $G=4\pi^2$, radius $1:1.8$ as I read the data in the paper as Jupiter and Saturn having radii of about $5$ and $8.5$ AU. For the masses took the ratios as sun:jup:sat=$1:3.33e{-}4:1e{-}3$. This behaves as expected for an order 4 method for time steps in the region of $0.0001$ to $0.005$ of the Jupiter period. The fraction oscillates around 16. This is as expected, as the angular velocity also depends on the time step, so that even for the unperturbed circular motions the errors can accumulate and cancel.

Comment: How do you advance the "other bodies"? Do you update their positions according to the times of the stages of the RK method?

Comment: I estimate the position of every planet but the perturbed one individually. So in the case we're considering, first I consider the Sun-Saturn system: I estimate Saturn position with a complete run of RK and than I use the results to estimte the perturbed Jupiter position doing a second complete RK run. For complete run I mean from the first iteration to the n-th. Of course both solutions are estimated using the same time grid. It's not asked to me to consider the rest of the planets in the case of Sun-Jupiter-Saturn system.

Comment: And what exactly do you do to get the half-step values in the second and third stage of RK4? If you only give $O(h)$ correct data you can only get $O(h)$ results. The same if you use mean values, this gives a piecewise linear external input, thus $O(h^2)$ correct, so that the result will also be maximally $O(h^2)$ correct.

Comment: I think I badly wrote the previous comment. For instance I meant I first calculate the solution for just Saturn around the Sun (so the entire set of positions of Saturn along the integration time $t_f$), using RK4. Than I use this solution to get Jupiter solution over $t_f$, since the perturbative term in the equations depends on Saturn position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain further what I wrote in the comments: Your function has the form `F(t,x,co,xo)` where `x` is the state, `co` the constants for the other objects and `xo` the dynamical data for the other objects.

**Variant 1:** You will get an order 1 approximation out of RK4 if you use the external dynamic in the RK4 loop as (in python notation)

```python
dx1 = dt*F(t[k]       , x[k]        , co, xo[k])
dx2 = dt*F(t[k]+0.5*dt, x[k]+0.5*dx1, co, xo[k])
dx3 = dt*F(t[k]+0.5*dt, x[k]+0.5*dx2, co, xo[k])
dx4 = dt*F(t[k]+    dt, x[k]+    dx3, co, xo[k])
x[k+1]=x[k]+(dx1+2*dx2+2*dx3*dx4)/6
```

**Variant 2:** You will get an order 2 approximation if you use linear interpolation as in

```python
dx1 = dt*F(t[k]       , x[k]        , co, xo[k])
dx2 = dt*F(t[k]+0.5*dt, x[k]+0.5*dx1, co, 0.5*(xo[k]+xo[k+1]))
dx3 = dt*F(t[k]+0.5*dt, x[k]+0.5*dx2, co, 0.5*(xo[k]+xo[k+1]))
dx4 = dt*F(t[k]+    dt, x[k]+    dx3, co, xo[k+1])
x[k+1]=x[k]+(dx1+2*dx2+2*dx3*dx4)/6
```

**Variant 3:** To get an error that goes down in 4th order with the step size, you need to integrate the other objects with double the rate and half the step size (or find an order 4 interpolation for the data) so that the loop then reads as

```python
dx1 = dt*F(t[k]       , x[k]        , co, xo[2*k])
dx2 = dt*F(t[k]+0.5*dt, x[k]+0.5*dx1, co, xo[2*k+1])
dx3 = dt*F(t[k]+0.5*dt, x[k]+0.5*dx2, co, xo[2*k+1])
dx4 = dt*F(t[k]+    dt, x[k]+    dx3, co, xo[2*k+2])
x[k+1]=x[k]+(dx1+2*dx2+2*dx3*dx4)/6
```

**Variant 4:** Of course, having a piecewise polynomial interpolation `xo_interp(t)` of  satisfying accuracy for the external data and using that same interpolation function for all step sizes in the RK4 experiment should also restore the 4th order

```python
dx1 = dt*F(t[k]       , x[k]        , co, xo_interp(t[k]))
dx2 = dt*F(t[k]+0.5*dt, x[k]+0.5*dx1, co, xo_interp(t[k]+0.5*dt))
dx3 = dt*F(t[k]+0.5*dt, x[k]+0.5*dx2, co, xo_interp(t[k]+0.5*dt))
dx4 = dt*F(t[k]+    dt, x[k]+    dx3, co, xo_interp(t[k+1]))
x[k+1]=x[k]+(dx1+2*dx2+2*dx3*dx4)/6
```

Comment: Ok, so it seems I have at least two problems actually: the one which causes the order 1 problem when I consider a perturbing object and the one that causes the spikes. I modified the code in order to solve the first one as explained in your answer and now $F_h$ is better, meaning that at least the flat parts of the $F_h$ plot are around $16$, using variant 3. But why `xo` is "seen" as order $1$ if I evaluated it with RK4? In other words, why does variant $1$ give me an order $1$ `x` approsimation if `xo` was evaluated using RK4?

Comment: Because the step function $x_o([t/dt]·dt)$ has error $O(dt)$ against $x_o(t)$, the difference is a saw-tooth function with height $\simeq x_o'(t)dt$. This gives an error $O(dt^2)$ in each step, which accumulates to an error of $O(t·dt)$ over the course of the integration. Similarly one knows that $\frac{x_o(t+dt)+x_o(t)}2-x_o(t+\frac12 dt)\simeq \frac12x_o''(t)dt^2$, so that variant 2 gives an error of $O(dt^2)$ in each step against a step with higher-order exact $x_o$ values.

Comment: Oh ok, I wasn't considering the error accumulation over time. Thank you very much!